# org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -1 , inner query fails

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

I am getting an exception on executing below MySQL query 
 hibernate dialect used is org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
following is my simple query.

String queryString=  "select action,user_role ,action_desc , action_timestamp, action_done  from event_details  Where  (general_type =1 or disco_type =1 or mask_type =1) and hadoop_type =0 AND COALESCE(source,'Structured') IN ('Both','Structured') and COALESCE(user_id,-1) =1 and Date(action_timestamp) between '2014-01-09' and  '2014-04-09' ";

Query query = session.createSQLQuery(queryString);
List list= query = query.list();  ...... This line throws exception.

when same query is executed for count i.e select count(*) from (queryString ) t1;
Then it gets executed fine.

Please suggest what could be the problem ? and how can solve it ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved after adding Scalars to the query.